# Get value of div content using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html and I want to get the value of the div which is  "Other"
How can I do this with jQuery?

```
 <div class="readonly_label" id="field-function_purpose">
        Other
 </div>
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to extract the content of the div

```
var text = $('#field-function_purpose').text()
```

Comment: Can you tell why the `.val` will not work in above case. Thanks!

Comment: @Unbreakable .val is for input elements

Answer (score 10):

your div looks like this:

```
<div class="readonly_label" id="field-function_purpose">Other</div>
```

With jquery you can easily get inner content:

Use `.html()` : HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

```
var text = $('#field-function_purpose').html();
```

[Read more about jquery .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

or

Use `.text()` : Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

```
var text = $('#field-function_purpose').text();
```

[Read more about jquery .text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 4):

You can get div content using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) in jquery

```
var divContent = $('#field-function_purpose').text();
console.log(divContent);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YWfsB/)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the method [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) of jQuery to get all the content of the text contained in the element. The **text()** method also returns the textual content of the child elements.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum elit sit ut, consectetur adipiscing dolor.</p> 
</div>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      var divContent = $('#box').text();
      alert(divContent);
    });
  });
```

You can see an example here: [How to get the text content of an element with jQuery](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-get-the-text-content-of-an-element-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#field-function_purpose')` will get you the element with ID `field-function_purpose`, which is your div element. `text()` returns you the content of the div.

```
var x = $('#field-function_purpose').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get value of div content using jquery.

```js
    $(".showplaintext").click(function(){
        alert($(".plain").text());
    });
    
    // Show text content of formatted paragraph
    $(".showformattedtext").click(function(){
        alert($(".formatted").text());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="plain">Exploring the zoo, we saw every kangaroo jump and quite a few carried babies. </p>
    <p class="formatted">Exploring the zoo<strong>, we saw every kangaroo</strong> jump <em><sup> and quite a </sup></em>few carried <a href="#"> babies</a>.</p>
    <button type="button" class="showplaintext">Get Plain Text</button>
    <button type="button" class="showformattedtext">Get Formatted Text</button>
```

Taken from @ [Get the text inside an element using jQuery](http://www.jquerypot.com/how-to-get-the-text-inside-an-element-using-jquery/)