# Get text next to img Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code

```js
$('.arrow img').click(function() {
 var text = $('.arrow div').contents().text();
 alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow">
 <div><img src="images/flechedroite.png" /> Hello the world</div>
 <div><img src="images/flechedroite.png" /> Give us your feedback</div>
 <div><img src="images/flechedroite.png" /> We love sharing stuff</div>      
</div>
```

What I want is for each image, display in `alert()` the text next to it.
I try something but it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of div content using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581683/get-value-of-div-content-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

you can try `.closest()` and get text for parent div

```
$('.arrow img').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).closest('div').text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: Indeed, I don't even think to use closest(). It works ! Thanks ;)

Comment: @CorentinBranquet Welcome anytime .. Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse to parent div element using `.parent()` along with `.text()` to find text in it:

```
$('.arrow img').click(function() {
     alert($(this).parent().text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$('.arrow img').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).parent().contents().filter(function(){
        return this.nodeType == 3;//if node type is textNode
    });
    alert(text);
});
```

Check references: [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent),  [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) and [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextSibling.textContent` from js:

```js
$('.arrow img').click(function() {
  var text = this.nextSibling.textContent;
  $('pre').html(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow">
  <div>
    <img src="images/flechedroite.png" />Hello the world</div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/flechedroite.png" />Give us your feedback</div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/flechedroite.png" />We love sharing stuff</div>
</div>

<pre></pre>
```