# How to find the text content of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is simple but I just can't seem to work it out. I'm trying to get the text value within a div. The code below is from a search drop down result so the user will click on the search result and what is clicked on should then populate another div. But for the moment I just want to get the value within the div either "1" or "2" as a variable.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      .number:hover{
          cursor: pointer;
      }
  </style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#search_result').click(function() {
var txt =     
$(this).closest("#search_result").next(".number").find(".number").text();
alert(txt);
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="search_result" style="border-radius: 2px; border:   
1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); z-index: 3; position: absolute; background-
color: white; width: 76.46%; display: block;">

<div class="dropdowncontainer" style="z-index:1000; border-bottom: 1px solid   
#E6E6E6; height:20%">

<div class="dropdown" style="height:20%; width:100%; z-index:10">
<div style="height:12px; width:50%; position: float-right">
<img src="1.jpg" style="height:100%; position: float-right" width="60px">
</div>
<div class="number" style="margin-top:-10px; width:100%">
<font color="#2947F2">
<b>1</b>
</font>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdowncontainer" style="z-index:1000; border-bottom: 1px solid   
#E6E6E6; height:20%">
<div class="dropdown" style="height:20%; width:100%; z-index:10">
<div style="height:12px; width:50%; position: float-right">
<img src="2.jpg" style="height:100%; position: float-right" width="60px">
</div>
<div class="number" style="margin-top:-10px; width:100%">
<font color="#2947F2">
<b>2</b>
</font>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581683/get-value-of-div-content-using-jquery

Comment: @DeninKorjenic hi sorry that does seem to work. The "number" div is under the "search_result" div

Comment: @SillyQuestionBoy If my answer is correct please mark it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might suit your needs?
I am using `$.html()` for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search_result .number').click(function() {
    var txt =
      $(this).find("b").html();
    alert(txt);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search_result" style="border-radius: 2px; border:   
1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); z-index: 3; position: absolute; background-
color: white; width: 76.46%; display: block;">

  <div class="dropdowncontainer" style="z-index:1000; border-bottom: 1px solid   
#E6E6E6; height:20%">

    <div class="dropdown" style="height:20%; width:100%; z-index:10">
      <div style="height:12px; width:50%; position: float-right">

      </div>
      <div class="number" style="margin-top:-10px; width:100%">
        <font color="#2947F2">
<b>1</b>
</font>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdowncontainer" style="z-index:1000; border-bottom: 1px solid   
#E6E6E6; height:20%">
    <div class="dropdown" style="height:20%; width:100%; z-index:10">
      <div style="height:12px; width:50%; position: float-right">

      </div>
      <div class="number" style="margin-top:-10px; width:100%">
        <font color="#2947F2">
<b>2</b>
</font>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree. The real problem was that the jQuery selector wasn't getting the `<b>` tags which is what have the actual number texts. You should actually just be able to use `.text()` though?

Comment: I fixed my code. Yeah text will work as well, but I am unsure of what overhead may come with that.

Comment: Currently though, the output is 12. jQuery is returning both `<b>`'s

Comment: Hmm thats odd. My browser(chrome) is working as expected.

Comment: Perfect it seems!

Answer (score 1):

I think it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_result").on('click', 'div.number', function(event){  
    alert($(event.currentTarget).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search_result" style="border-radius: 2px; border:   
1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); z-index: 3; position: absolute; background-
color: white; width: 76.46%; display: block;">

<div class="dropdowncontainer" style="z-index:1000; border-bottom: 1px solid   
#E6E6E6; height:20%">

<div class="dropdown" style="height:20%; width:100%; z-index:10">
<div style="height:12px; width:50%; position: float-right">
<img src="1.jpg" style="height:100%; position: float-right" width="60px">
</div>
<div class="number" style="margin-top:-10px; width:100%">
<font color="#2947F2">
<b>1</b>
</font>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdowncontainer" style="z-index:1000; border-bottom: 1px solid   
#E6E6E6; height:20%">
<div class="dropdown" style="height:20%; width:100%; z-index:10">
<div style="height:12px; width:50%; position: float-right">
<img src="2.jpg" style="height:100%; position: float-right" width="60px">
</div>
<div class="number" style="margin-top:-10px; width:100%">
<font color="#2947F2">
<b>2</b>
</font>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

helps you: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/834/)

Comment: Great use of delegation to the number divs. However, this is not a complete solution as the question was to get the value 1 or 2, not everything else in the `.number div`. Suggest changing to `$("#search_result").on('click', 'div.number b', function(event){  
    alert($(this).html());
  });`

Comment: @bobjoe thanks this works very well too excellent suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You should use only this 
$(this).text();

Comment: That won't always work though because the `$(this)` can be the `div` or the `b` depending on where the click is.