# I can not get text value in a div by using val() or innerHTML or

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried val(), innerHTML, innerText, value but it return undefined or blank. why?

```js
var a = $('#test').val();
alert(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div id="test">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#test').val()` will take the **value** property, e.g., in `<input value="myValue" />`. Just use `$('#test').text()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of div content using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581683/get-value-of-div-content-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the innerText of a node you should use .text();

Source: https://api.jquery.com/text/

```js
var a = $('#test').text();
alert(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div id="test">hello</div>
</div>
```