# How to pull values from divs to variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a simple progress bar widget http://jsfiddle.net/vibrasphere/wkcfg5y2/7/ and it works, but only if you set values inside variables e.g. `var likes = 1;`, but we need to pull values from inside the divs e.g. `<div class="like">1</div>`.

So `var likes =`  has to be showing the number values from the div class somehow?

```js
var likes = 1;
var dislikes = 5;
var total = likes + dislikes;
var likePerc = (likes / total) * 100;
var dislikePerc = (dislikes / total) * 100;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".likes").css("width", likePerc);
  $(".dislikes").css("width", dislikePerc);
});
```

```css
.progressBar {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
}

.likes {
  background-color: #0F0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
}

.dislikes {
  background-color: #F00;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vote">
  <div class="like">1</div>
  <div class="dislike">5</div>
</div>

<div class='progressBar'>
  <div class='likes'></div>
  <div class='dislikes'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `var likes = $(".like").text()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get value of div content using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581683/get-value-of-div-content-using-jquery)

Comment: var likes = +$('div.like').text();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var likes = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("like")[0].innerText);
  var dislikes = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("dislike")[0].innerText);
  var total = likes + dislikes;
  var likePerc = (likes / total) * 100;
  var dislikePerc = (dislikes / total) * 100;
  $(".likes").css("width", likePerc);
  $(".dislikes").css("width", dislikePerc);
});
```

```css
.progressBar {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
}

.likes {
  background-color: #0F0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
}

.dislikes {
  background-color: #F00;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vote">
  <div class="like">1</div>
  <div class="dislike">5</div>
</div>

<div class='progressBar'>
  <div class='likes'></div>
  <div class='dislikes'></div>
</div>
```

This does it!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var likes = parseInt($('.like').text(),10);
    var dislikes = parseInt($('.dislike').text(),10);
    var total = likes+dislikes;
    var likePerc = (likes/total)*100;
    var dislikePerc = (dislikes/total)*100;
    $(".likes").css("width", likePerc);
    $(".dislikes").css("width", dislikePerc); 
    
});
```

```css
.progressBar {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
}

.likes {
    background-color: #0F0;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
}

.dislikes {
    background-color: #F00;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vote">
  <div class="like">100</div>
  <div class="dislike">50</div>
</div>

<div class='progressBar'>
     <div class='likes'></div>
     <div class='dislikes'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The progress bar size change on different values. Thanks for contributing, correct answer selected above, the bar size is not affected.

Comment: See the edited version of the code I wrote, in this way, you can get your job done with a shorter code. @user3108268